# How to clear the output screen in Code::blocks?

Tags: c, codeblocks

in turbo c++ you could do it like this

```
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
     clrscr();
}
```

But in code blocks i cant use this.. :(

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/4z18T05o/

Answer (score 6):

You can use `system("cls");` with the header `#include <cstdlib>`. "cls" is a Batch command that works on DOS/Windows. On other systems(UNIX based systems) you might use:
`cout << "\x1b[2J\x1b[1;1H" << flush;`

Never, I repeat, NEVER use "conio.h". Is a deprecated library, that is not a part of standard, and only a few compilers have it.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
cout<<"Hello World ! ! !\n";
system("pause");
system("cls");
}
```

100% working code.
You need iostream and namespace std only for cout cin etc. The windows header has "cls". It is like `system ( " MSDOS_COMMAND " );` . Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Clear Output Screen - Depends on compilers and Operating System, we can use one of the following method depending on the compiler.

- Using `clrscr()` - For TurboC Compiler
- Using `system("cls")` - For TurboC Compiler
- Using `system("clear")` - For gcc/g++ compiler in Linux

Answer (score 1):

The easiest most straightforward way is to just do it through system function call:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    system("cls");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//try without this-- " using namespace std ".

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream.h>
int main()
{
//using namespace std
 clrscr();
}
```

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is ok

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello!");
    getche();
    system ("cls");
    printf("Bye!");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `system("cls");` (for windows) or `system("clear");` (for GNU/Linux) with header `#include <stdlib.h>` (If you are programming in C Language) or `#include <cstdlib>` (If you are programming in C++)

Note: `#include <conio.h>` is not a standard library header file and only provided by few compilers (e.g. TurboC++).