# C++. related to code::blocks ide. the "object is not declared in this scope" error

Tags: c++

I am using code::blocks. I used to use turbo C++ 3.0.

I wrote the following code and got an error that is kinda impossible:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    clrscr();

    char name[20];

    cout<<"\nEnter your name:";

    cin.getline(name,20);

    cout<<"\nName stored";

    clrscr();

    cout<<"\nName:"<<name;

    getch();
    return 0;

}
```

it is showing the error that cout,cin and clrscr() are not declared in this scope. I dont understand why this is being shown.

I ran the same code in Turbo C++ 3.0 which was the compiler i used earlier. And i got no such error there. Kindly help rectify this error.

please tell me what is the problem here and why it is not working.

Comment: If you post a question about errors, please always include the _actual_ errors, unedited.

Comment: Try this for a workaround: [How to clear the output screen in Code::blocks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938331/how-to-clear-the-output-screen-in-codeblocks?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's why people suggest you use standard library instead of relying on a compiler specific API.

TurboC++ has `<conio.h>` which is not a standard C++/C header.

work-around:

For linux  : [libconio.h](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linux-conioh/)

For windows:

```
  #include <conio.h>
  #define clrscr() system("cls");
  #define getch() kbhit()
```

Comment: Turbo C++ is from a time long before we had a standard library, so it wasn't an option.

Comment: but kbhit does not do the same thing as getch(). then what must we do?

Comment: @IcyFlame I think there is a `getch()` in windows's `conio.h` header file.

Answer (score 1):

Conio.h works for borland compilers.  Use curses.h. Turbo c++ is based on borland compilers.

MingGw is the default compiler for Code::blocks, and that is based on GNU-compiler. The header will be imported, but most functions will not be available.

Comment: An assumption on my part, that error is common when not using borland compiler. He said he used to use Turbo C++ and i assumed that he changed to something non-borland.